# Mi app winform inicia en segundo plano desde el iis

Tags: c#, .net

He desarrollado una aplicacion winform para captahuellas y además he creado un web api que me invoca este winform. La idea es llamar mi url de webapi desde otra aplicación y que mi web api abra la aplicación de windows form. Esto lo hago desde mi webapi con `Process.Start(AppCaptaHuellas.exe)`.
En ejecución local me funciona perfecto, pero al desplegarlo en mi IIS local y ejecutar mi web api la aplicación windows form se queda en *Procesos de segundo plano* por lo que el usuario no la puede ver.
Mi webapi y mi winform están desarrollados con framework .net 4.72 en c#.

¿Qué puedo hacer para solventar esto?

Comment: A ver, tu tienes un servidor con una API y un cliente que llama esa api. Quieres que se abra una app winforms en el cliente????

Comment: Desde un sitio web, mandar a abrir un .exe? Esto no es posible por seguridad, te dejo otra [pregunta relacionada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444551/how-to-open-exe-file-on-client-system-in-a-web-application)

Comment: Buenos días!
Correcto, tengo mi servidor local con una API y un cliente que llama a esa api, a través de una URL y necesito que se abra el winforms cuando el cliente introduce en su navegador la url del api, pero ésta winform se queda como proceso en segundo plano y en local todo me funciona perfecto.

Comment: No se puede hacer lo que queres... la web es dentro del navegador.. las paginas son servidas por IIS.. el exe, que vos abris, se abre en el servidor.. no en segundo plano, en el servidor. No viaja al cliente.. porque ese codigo se ejecuto en el servidor. Aca, lo que hicieron, muestra que no se entiende como funciona una pagina web, ni una aplicacion de escritorio. No le va a abrir a nadie esa app, por mas que las copies en los clientes, porque los que tienen que ejecutar codigo para abrirlo (si el navegador te dejara) seria el cliente.

Comment: Para resolver esto, basicamente necesitas replantear absolutamente toda la idea. No conozco tu nivel de experienceia, pero necesitas un arquitecto que diseñe una solucion segun los requerimientos que tenes...

Comment: Hola @gbianchi agradezco mucho por tu pronta respuesta, solo soy programadora poco conozco de diseño de solución, me gustaria consultarte lo que en realidad necesito es que neceito desarrolladar una aplicacion que se conecte con un dispositivo biometrico que capte huellas datilares y las guarde en base de datos mysql, adicional a esto se requiera llamar de una aplicacion externa este aplicacion de biometrico para recibir un ID de empleado y con esto guardar en base de datos la huella en el idempleado correspondiente.

Comment: @gbianchi   Mi primer intento fue con un webforms pero no me reconocia la huella (queria crear una metodo similar al  DefWndProc de system.windos.form  pero no lo logré) me reconocía el dispositivo, lo abría pero no captura la huella, es decir, no encontre en webform un evento que reconociera la conexion inmediata al tocar el sensor, tendras alguna idea que me pueda ayudar con esto?

Muchas gracias
Saludos

Comment: Mi primera pregunta es.. porque necesitas que sea web? aca hay que replantear la solucion ;)... pero eso, segun mi punto de vista, sin saber absolutamente nada de lo que necesitas.. pero el camino no es por aca...

Comment: Muchas gracias @gbianchi
Necesito que sea web ya que mi app se quiere llamar de una tercera aplicacion de la cual voy a recibir un Id

Saludos

Comment: Eso, no quiere decir que tenga que ser web.. puede ser una api que recibe informacion de cualquier lado... y es muy probable que si puedas usar el lector en una app web... porque, con la api correspondietne, no deja de ser como un teclado..

Comment: Bueno, yo intenté y una de mis alternativas fue la de crear una app web y se conectaba con un lector de huellas pero no di con el evento que responda al sensor que es cuando se coloca el dedo sobre el dispositivo y seria en el momento en que la aplicacion capture la huella como imagen y guarde en base de datos pero no logre esa comunicacion del sensor con mi aap web

Comment: Habria que ver que sensor es y la especificacion... lamento no poder dar mas que ayudas vagas... no conozco tanto del tema sensores.

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias @gbianchi por todas tus respuestas y gran ayuda

Muy agradecida
Saludos